# Handling a producer and consumer using Kafka-python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, broker, kafka-python

First I would like to say that I am a newbie to Kafka and also stackoverflow, So I am sorry if I am not asking this in the right way.
I am trying to implement the producer-consumer using kafka-python.
But its not working properly

I have the zookeeper installed and its up and running. I have up the kafka-server also. But when I am running the consumer and producer through pycharm, the messages are not getting received by the receiver.The consumer keeps on running but the producer stops.

consumer.py

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', group_id='test-consumer-group', 
bootstrap_servers=['my_ip:9092'], api_version=(0, 10, 1),
                     auto_offset_reset='earliest')
print("Consuming messages")
for msg in consumer:
    print(msg)
```

producer.py

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

print('above producer')
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['my_ip:9092'], api_version=(0, 10, 1),
                         compression_type=None
                         )
print('after producer')
for _ in range(100):
    producer.send('test', b'HELLO NITHIN chandran')

print('after sending messages')
```

In the place of my_ip, I have provided with my system ip address from ipconfig.

consumer.py Output -

```
Consuming messages
```

The consumer.py doesnt stop running

producer.py Output -

```
above producer
after producer
after sending messages

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The producer.py stops running and the process is finished as shown in the output.

Please help me in resolving this issue.
All help are appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Can you check the topic's data in data dir of Kafka? Please check that there is anything in the topic or not?

Comment: How do I do that? There is no data directory in Kafka. There are only bin,config,libs,site-docs,LICENSE,NOTICE.

Comment: you should look at the config file in `config/server.properties`. probably it is in the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: Could u please be a bit more specific. Like what should I be looking for in the ```config/server.properties``` file

Comment: Of course. there is a `log.dirs` config, in this file. it specifies the directory of storing topics' data. in that directory, there are many folders with your topics name. find your topic and open the log file.

Comment: Yes there are 4 files but none with my topic name. There is one LOCK file also. But all the files are empty the size is 0KB.

Comment: ```https://www.learningjournal.guru/article/kafka/installing-kafka-on-windows/```

Comment: I had set everything up through the above mentioned link, this is through the command prompt

Comment: When I run the consumer through the command prompt, I get the below mentioned warning  now

Comment: `WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-52241] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [test-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)`

Comment: Probably you have problem with `advertised.listeners`. set Kafka address to localhost instead of your IP

Comment: Yes I have used localhost only

Comment: I have used localhost for both `advertised.listeners` and `listeners` but still the issue persists

Comment: Please follow the conversation here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198510/kafka-issues

Comment: It says I must have 20 reputations to talk in that

Comment: but i am not able to type anything in there

Comment: Sorry, these comments are being conversational. I can talk to you about your problem in another place. please suggest somewhere.

Comment: Yaa sure Is LinkedIn okay?

Comment: or where do all normally do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, the problem is about your broker configuration. Please set it to initial configuration, just change the `log.dirs` to the path that you want to store Kafka data.
After changing the config file follow these steps:

- Stop zookeeper and kafka
- Clear both  kafka and zookeeper data dir
- Run zookeeper and kafa
- Start consumer and producer